# Solution for Must use scalare variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
protected void showData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select @orderID, @buyersName, @deliveryAddress, @productID, @productName, @category, @image, @price, @paymentMode, @holderName, @OrderDate, @PhoneNo from tblOrderDetails", con);
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This code is showing an error:

> Must use scalar variable @orderId

What do I have to correct?

Comment: Remove all `@` sign from column names (which marks variable names), you're trying to SELECT from columns.

Comment: "This code is showing" where? When? Does the compiler report an error about a particular line of code, or does the editor reject your typing? We shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
"select @orderID, @buyersName, @deliveryAddress, @productID, @productName, @category, @image, @price, @paymentMode, @holderName, @OrderDate, @PhoneNo from tblOrderDetails", con);
```

This code is wrong.You need to remove @ from the column name.
This [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dataadapter-in-C-Sharp/) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

using @ if u awnt insert parameter, in this case no need anymore
just like this:

```
"select orderID, buyersName, deliveryAddress, productID, productName, category, image, price, paymentMode, holderName, OrderDate, PhoneNo from tblOrderDetails", con);
```